Is every ultraconnected semi-regular space an indiscrete space?

A space is ultraconnected provided the space has no disjoint nonempty closed sets.

A space is semiregular provided it has a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of open sets such that $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(O)) = O$ for every $O \in \mathcal{B}$.


π-Base, Search for ultraconnected+semiregular reveals only indiscrete spaces (spaces for which only $\emptyset$ and $X$ are open). Is it a theorem that every ultraconnected and semiregular space is indiscrete? This theorem holds if you strengthen semiregular to regular: π-Base, Search for ultraconnected+regular+~Indiscrete

No. Consider any excluded point topology on $X$ with at least $3$ points, with the excluded point $p$. Then $\{\{x\}:x\in X\setminus\{p\}\}\cup\{X\}$ forms a basis for the space. Note that for each $x\in X\setminus\{p\}$, we have $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(\{x\}))=\operatorname{int}(\{x,p\})=\{x\}$, and of course $\operatorname{int}(\operatorname{cl}(X))=\operatorname{int}(X)=X$. This shows the space is semiregular.
The space is also ultraconnected, since every two non-empty closed sets intersects at $p$.

Nice! With this, the list resulting from the search "~$R_0$+Semiregular" isn't empty.
